# Python/SQL - How the cursor functions

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

In my code I have a function that needs to return either a string or None depending on what is present in the database. However at the moment the result is a list with the string answer inside, or None. Is there any change that could be made that would result in just a string or None being returned, rather than having to index the list?

Here is the code:

```
def retrieve_player_name(username):
    param = [(username)]
    command = ("""
                SELECT username FROM players
                WHERE username = ?
                """)
    result = cur.execute(command, param).fetchone()
    if result is not None:
        return result[0]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A database cursors fetches entire rows, not values.
Even a row with a single value inside is still a row.

If you don't want to write `row[0]` multiple times, create a helper function `execute_and_return_a_single_value_from_query()`.